# java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy48.select(Unknown Source) in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, allure, atlas

I am facing the below exception when running my automation code.

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy48.select(Unknown Source)

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

It seems there is no issue with the code because the same code works fine in my colleague's machine. Is this exception related to some configuration while set up the project. Can someone please help.

Console Error

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy41.select(Unknown Source)
at com.appbuddy.steps.GW1Steps.selectDataSourceWithoutAuthenticate(GW1Steps.java:85)
at com.appbuddy.testng.tests.grids.GridFormatTestsSf.qa227(GridFormatTestsSf.java:330)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.retryFailed(TestInvoker.java:204)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:58)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.(java.lang.Class,int)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
at io.qameta.atlas.core.internal.DefaultMethodExtension.invoke(DefaultMethodExtension.java:24)
at io.qameta.atlas.core.internal.AtlasMethodHandler.invokeWithRetry(AtlasMethodHandler.java:65)
at io.qameta.atlas.core.internal.AtlasMethodHandler.invoke(AtlasMethodHandler.java:41)
... 31 more

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have attached the console error. Will it help to sort out the issue ?